# What does sqllocaldb tracing do?

Tags: asp.net, localdb

The [sqllocaldb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx) command has a *trace* option that can be set on or off, but not a clue as to what tracing it presumably controls, or where the trace output might be found.

Does this option actually do anything?  What would it trace and where would the trace output be?